# How to make the information in a dropdownlist change

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio

So i want to make a drop down list that displays new information if you select different radio buttons.
And im struggling.For Example if radio button 1 is selected the information in dropbox must change to popcorn and sweets.

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <style type="text/css">
        .auto-style1 {
            margin-left: 18px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div>
            <asp:RadioButton ID="RadioButton1" runat="server" OnCheckedChanged="RadioButton1_CheckedChanged" Text="Day" />
        </div>
        <asp:RadioButton ID="RadioButton2" runat="server" Text="Night" />
        <br />
        <br />
        <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server">
            <asp:ListItem>Cream Soda</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>coke</asp:ListItem>
        </asp:DropDownList>
        <br />
        <br />
        <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Name"></asp:Label>
        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" CssClass="auto-style1" Width="139px"></asp:TextBox>
        <br />
        <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text="Seat No:"></asp:Label>
        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server" Width="140px"></asp:TextBox>
        <br />
        <br />
        <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Height="20px" Text="Add Choice" />
        <br />
        <asp:Label ID="Label3" runat="server"></asp:Label>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Is there any update? If your question has been solved , you can click '✔' to mark the appropriate reply as the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You must define autopostback="true" on the RadioButton, and then you need to handle the selected value in the codebehind, and re-fill the drop-down with a new item-list.

Page-Cycle will be like this

- Page_Load
- RadioButton2_Changed
- Page_LoadComplete

So make sure you either set the new content in RadioButton2_Changed, or in Page_LoadComplete. If you try to do it in Page_Load, you'll have the old value of radiobutton, and that will not work well ...

Comment: Thanks and the values someone told me i need 2 arrays but it seems like its not nessasary for this or where should i store the vlaues.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following steps to show the correspond information when you click the radio button.

First, you need to change your html file into the following:

```
<body>
   <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div>
            <asp:RadioButton ID="RadioButton1" runat="server" OnCheckedChanged="RadioButton1_CheckedChanged" Text="Day" GroupName="Ra"  AutoPostBack="true" />
        </div>
        <asp:RadioButton ID="RadioButton2" runat="server" Text="Night" OnCheckedChanged="RadioButton2_CheckedChanged" GroupName="Ra"  AutoPostBack="true"/>
        <br />
        <br />
        <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server">
        </asp:DropDownList>
        <br />
        <br />
        <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Name"></asp:Label>
        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" CssClass="auto-style1" Width="139px"></asp:TextBox>
        <br />
        <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text="Seat No:"></asp:Label>
        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server" Width="140px"></asp:TextBox>
        <br />
        <br />
        <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Height="20px" Text="Add Choice" />
        <br />
        <asp:Label ID="Label3" runat="server"></asp:Label>
    </form>
</body>
```

Second, you need to call the RadioButton1_CheckedChanged event and RadioButton2_CheckedChanged event to to add the listitem.

```
ListItem list1 = new ListItem("popcorn");
ListItem list2 = new ListItem("sweets");
ListItem list3 = new ListItem("Cream Soda");
ListItem list4 = new ListItem("coke");
protected void RadioButton1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(RadioButton1.Checked==true)
    {
        if (!DropDownList1.Items.Contains(list1) && !DropDownList1.Items.Contains(list2))
        {
            DropDownList1.Items.Clear();
            DropDownList1.Items.Add(list1);
            DropDownList1.Items.Add(list2);
        }  
    }
}
protected void RadioButton2_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (RadioButton2.Checked == true)
    {

        if (!DropDownList1.Items.Contains(list3) && !DropDownList1.Items.Contains(list4))
        {
            DropDownList1.Items.Clear();
            DropDownList1.Items.Add(list3);
            DropDownList1.Items.Add(list4);
        }
        
    }
}
```

Result:

[image]